# Stop installation based on criteria

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, setup-project

I am trying to check if a computer has the VC++ redistributable installed and the best way I have found to check for it is by running the following code:

```
bool CheckForVCRedist()
{
    bool install = false;

    if (!install) install = 5 == MsiQueryProductState("{196BB40D-1578-3D01-B289-BEFC77A11A1E}");
    if (!install) install = 5 == MsiQueryProductState("{DA5E371C-6333-3D8A-93A4-6FD5B20BCC6E}");
    if (!install) install = 5 == MsiQueryProductState("{C1A35166-4301-38E9-BA67-02823AD72A1B}");
    if (!install) install = 5 == MsiQueryProductState("{F0C3E5D1-1ADE-321E-8167-68EF0DE699A5}");
    if (!install) install = 5 == MsiQueryProductState("{1D8E6291-B0D5-35EC-8441-6616F567A0F7}");
    if (!install) install = 5 == MsiQueryProductState("{88C73C1C-2DE5-3B01-AFB8-B46EF4AB41CD}");

    return install;
}

[DllImport("msi.dll")]
private static extern int MsiQueryProductState(string product);
```

If any of the following are true, then my program will run correctly. I am trying to arrange it so that the installer stops based on the presence of the VC++ Redistributable. In the program installer cs file there is the following code:

```
protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    if (CheckForVCRedist())
    {
        base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("You are missing the VC ++ 2010 Redistributable. Please follow the link to get it:\nhttp://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555");
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any advice?

Edit: I don't have a custom action set up to run this as I thought overriding the method was the correct way to go... I now feel like that is wrong.

Edit[2013-02-28 10:36]: The error is not being thrown in the installer, is there a better way to stop the installer form installing?

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? When you say this doesn't work, does it not detect VC++ installation properly?

Comment: Well, the only way I can test is by installing the program and I am not getting any feed back on a computer which does not have the VC++ Redistributable. I will try adding a message box to the valid installation portion.

Comment: The thrown exception needs to get handled somehow. Otherwise it might be failing silently (maybe?). Could you check your eventlog for errors?

Comment: There are not even errors in the event log, is there a better way for me to cancel the installation at this point rather than throwing an error?

Comment: @BlazePhoenix The difference between overriding `Install` and `OnBeforeInstall` is in the way that they react to `InstallException`. `Install` shows a friendly message while `OnBeforeInstall` shows not such friendly message.

Comment: @BlazePhoenix Thank you for your feedback, Let me know if you gave it a chance to be accepted, I used this solution and it works properly, shows a message that I posted in screenshot and cancels the installation :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Sorry about the delay; just got caught up every time I went to up vote and select the answer. I do wish we had this two years ago, but hey, live and learn right?

Comment: Thank you for kind feedback :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a [`CustomAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx) and then override `Install`. Then you can make the setup cancel by throwing [`InstallException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    if (CheckForExceptionalCondition())
        throw new InstallException("Some message for user.");

    base.Install(savedState);
}
```

Then it shows a friendly message box during the installation and cancels the setup.

[image]